# Adding <br> breaks layout

Tags: html, css

In the header I have currency and a weather app.

If I add a `<br />` there

```
<h4>Curs valutar
```

here

```
<small>08 Aug 14</small></h4>
```

The way the weather is displayed changes.

Comment: yes, it does. br breaks the layout you were having. What do you want?

Comment: Try adding `display:block` to your `<small>` element.

Comment: Please provide an example here or using http://jsfiddle.net.  Linking to your website means that your question becomes invalid once the issue is fixed, and will make no sense to future readers.  As @C-linkNepal says, the `<br/>` is designed to add a "line break", so what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: As Niet the Dark Absol said, try to give display:block for <samll>..

Comment: A curiosity question. Why use `small` inside `h4`? Yes its a valid semantic, but in this specific case, what is there to gain?

Comment: I've tried adding `display:block` to the `<small>` element and I get the same result. What i want is for the date to be displayed on a new line and at the same time keep the weather app looking as it currently is. I can't really recreate the whole thing in jsfiddle.net, believe me I've tried.

Comment: You know for what tag `<br/>`? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your  tag apply `display:inline-block`. This will fix your problem.

```
<small style="display: inline-block;">08 Aug 14</small>
```

Answer (score 0):

on your small tag write css property display:inline-block

```
<h4>Curs valutar
<br />
<small style="display:inline-block">08 Aug 14</small></h4>
```